# Certificates check a what domain(s) is/are there in an IP address. How to do it with PHP?

Tags: php, ip, certificate, domain-name

How do certificates check an IP address against domain name(s)? What is the protocol and parameters etc? How to check how much domains are there in an IP address with PHP?

Comment: What kind of certificates are you talking about? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: If there are 20 domains being hosted at a specific IP address, there is no way (in general) to go from the IP address back to the DNS names that might point to it.  There is normally only one PTR record to the canonical forward name.  SSL certificate checks go by the name, and eg the HTTP protocol transfers the DNS name the user entered to the web server so that it knows what domain and thus certificate to match and return.

Comment: @deceze, the very simple/basic SSL certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no PHP tool that would do this. But there are services that maintain full(ish) reverse mapping databases, such as http://ipneighbor.com/

With PHP, at most you could look up the standard IP->Domain PTR record, but there's ever only one of those for any given IP - you wouldn't get all the domains using the IP. For that, people crawl the full DNS database (which is HUGE and fully distributed) and build their own reverse lookup maps.

Comment: not as good as http://www.domaintools.com/research/reverse-ip/ but at least it is free.